# Long running queries with Prisma on Planetscale timeout

Tags: serverless, prisma, planetscale

It would appear that Planetscale will timeout after 20s and stop the query. (also sometimes happens on Vercel's Postgres as well)

`Error occurred during query execution: ConnectorError(ConnectorError { user_facing_error: None, kind: QueryError(Server(ServerError { code: 1105, message: "target: schotw.-.primary: vttablet: rpc error: code = Aborted desc = transaction 1687744201628715261: ended at 2023-06-26 15:34:49.624 UTC (exceeded timeout: 20s) (CallerID: ************)", state: "HY000" })),  transient: false })`

Basically I am trying to convert a csv file to a database. the csv file is constructed in a way that it has relations, so i have a large upsert statement that joins the rows together in a relational way.

I totally understand why Planetscale or other serverless platforms would want to do something like this as it will protect against un-intentional mistakes and control their server load, but I am just uncertain how I can run a larger query on one of these services.

I have tried to run this on Planetscale an Vercel's Postgres DB.
I would not have expected this to run so long on the server as the same query would complete in fractions of a second on a localhost db.

I also had this working with no problems at all on firebase / firestore. In fact I could do multiple files at a time and it would be complete in seconds, but it would be easier to work with the data if it was in a relational db.

There is another post on this topic that no one has even commented on.
[Running Long Tasks via NodeJS + Prisma always loses connection? (ConnectorError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74942102/running-long-tasks-via-nodejs-prisma-always-loses-connection-connectorerror?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C44.7996)